# ActiveRecord::Deadlocked: PG::TRDeadlockDetected: ERROR: deadlock detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, transactions, database-deadlocks

Getting Postgresql Database deadlock error in ruby on rails while updating multiple records at once

`ActiveRecord::Deadlocked: PG::TRDeadlockDetected: ERROR: deadlock detected DETAIL: Process 140501 waits for ShareLock on transaction 42841495; blocked by process 140500. Process 140500 waits for ShareLock on transaction 42841496; blocked by process 1405`

on this line of code. It is updating some 800 users records.

`company.users.update_all(company_name: company.name)`

I am getting this on production environment but when I tried to reproduce it on local against the production dump, everything went smooth. Please help with the cause of this problem and a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Your database is busy. Perform the action [in batches](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-in_batches):

```rb
company.users.in_batches(of: 100) do |batch|
  batch.update_all(company_name: company.name)
end
```

Decrease the batch size if required.